# Unable to read configuration file in a test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, app-config

When running a unit test, the configuration file is not read properly.
However, when running from a console appplication context, the config file is read.

In the code below, when accessing ***var section*** after the assignment, it's null when running the test TestIoCInit() and not null when calling InitIoC() from console application.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIocInit()
    {
        InitIoC();
    }
    internal static void InitIoC()
    {
        IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer(); // the host app domain creates the unity container and pass it to the resolver, the resolver is a static member of IoC class, thus the container is static

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(unityContainer);

        var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        section.Configure(unityContainer);

        var unityResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(unityContainer);
        IoC.Initialize(unityResolver);
        new IoCTypeRegistrationTask(unityContainer).Execute();
    }
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a new class library project, and adding the [TestClass] attribute to it.
It worked perfectly without having have to copy the app.config file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try copying config file in the bin directory of the test project.
You should rename it to the

> Your_test_project_name.dll.config

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can add a post-build step to copy the project being tested's app.config into the directory of the test project (first add an app.config to the test project - it will get overwritten with the app.config from the project under test). This way every time you build the solution, you get a copy of the latest and greatest app.config version copied into the test project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ClassInit to copy missing resources (configuration files, unmanaged assemblies, data files) from the test's source/bin directory to the test result out directory.

To do this:

1. Start from the textContext.DeploymentDirectory and go up directories until you reach the solution's directory (use directory name, not full path, so it will work on other machines).

   1.1. If you do not reach it ( if test is running on build server), go up only until one directory higher that "TestResults" then into sub directory "Sources".
2. Calculate Test project's directory using path relative to solution's directory.
3. Copy required resources from project's directory or bin (don't forget to check configuration and platform if copying from bin).